# remove HTML element on click in Angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

This is my Directive. which display one Div on the body.

```
app.directive("autosuggest", function($rootScope) {
      return {
            scope: {
              doneFlag      : "=",
              groupFlag     : "=",
              inviteesFlag  : "=",
              init: '&'
            },
            templateUrl : "title.html",
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
                  }

});
```

And in title.html

```
<div class="showw">
   <img id="hideDivOnClick" src="ddd.png"/>
</div>
```

And i include directive like this

```
<div autosuggest="" done-Flag="1" group-Flag="1"  invitees-Flag="1" selected-Array="" ></div>
```

so when i click on image then this `<div autosuggest="" done-Flag="1" group-Flag="1"  invitees-Flag="1" selected-Array="" ></div>` parts gets remove from body. like remove element in  Javascript. how i will achive this in angularJS?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simply create a directive, that adds a function that will remove the html of the element. Then you can just stick it on an ng-click. I made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qDhT9/

```
// in the directive
scope.remove = function() {
    elt.html('');
};
// in the dom
<div remove-on-click ng-click="remove()"> 
    REMOVE ME 
</div>
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Also @hassassin can we apply ng class to custom directive. Like `<div id="autosuggest" class="autosuggest"  ng-class="{'Show-Class':displayDivCss==true}"  autosuggest="" done-Flag="1" group-Flag="1"  invitees-Flag="1" selected-Array="" ></div>`

Comment: sure, it will control the class on the div

Comment: this is not working. i was check condition also inside ng-class.but it will not apply show-class to div.so can you tell me other way to apply conditional class.

Comment: ng-class is correct. This is a different question than your original, but here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/qDhT9/6/

Answer (score 24):

Use below in your directive.

**Directive**

```
app.directive("removeMe", function() {
      return {
            link:function(scope,element,attrs)
            {
                element.bind("click",function() {
                    element.remove();
                });
            }
      }

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="showw" remove-me>
   <img id="hideDivOnClick" src="ddd.png"/>
</div>
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qDhT9/2/)</kbd>

Comment: This will only remove the IMG element, but that is easily addressed.

Comment: Also, jquery is unnecessary.  You can just use element.parent().remove() inside of the click handler.

Answer (score 11):

For clearing/removing html elements, we can use the following methods

```
var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#divID' ) );
myEl.empty();  //clears contents

var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#divID' ) );
myEl.remove();   //removes element
```

Reference : http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2014/08/empty-or-remove-element-using-angularjs.html#.Vd0_6vmqqkp

Comment: It used to work with Angular 1. Not sure if there are changes with newer versions. remove function should still be good I guess!

Answer (score 1):

A more robust adaptation of Aparna's answer, you can use the $document service which acts as a wrapper for the browser's 'window.document' object. So instead of accessing 'document' variable globally you can access the '$document' object as a dependency. This helps to make your code more testable.

eg:

```
app.controller('exampleCtrl', function($scope, $document) {
  $scope.deleteArticle = function(id) {
    var articleRow = angular.element($document[0].querySelector('div[data-articleid="'+id+'"]'));
    articleRow.remove();
  };
});
```