# Remove element on click - using AngularJS Directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create an angular directive which is used to remove the element from DOM when user clicks on it. I saw answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595774/remove-html-element-on-click-in-angular-js) and tried with both methods given in the answers but not able to replicate the same. This is my code

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <title>abc</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p remove-me>Remove This Element</p>
</body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive("removeMe", function($rootScope) {
      return {
            link:function(scope,element,attrs)
            {
                element.bind("click",function() {
                    element.remove();
                });
            }
      }
});
```

I am getting the below error on page loading

**Console-Error**

```
angular.min.js:117 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20removeMeDirective
    at Error (native)
    at file:///C:/Users/SARATH%20S%20NAIR/Desktop/abcd/angular.min.js:6:412
    at file:///C:/Users/SARATH%20S%20NAIR/Desktop/abcd/angular.min.js:43:84
    at Object.d [as get] (file:///C:/Users/SARATH%20S%20NAIR/Desktop/abcd/angular.min.js:40:344)
    at file:///C:/Users/SARATH%20S%20NAIR/Desktop/abcd/angular.min.js:43:146
    at d (file:///C:/Users/SARATH%20S%20NAIR/Desktop/abcd/angular.min.js:40:344)
    at e (file:///C:/Users/SARATH%20S%20NAIR/Desktop/abcd/angular.min.js:41:78)
    at Object.invoke (file:///C:/Users/SARATH%20S%20NAIR/Desktop/abcd/angular.min.js:41:163)
    at file:///C:/Users/SARATH%20S%20NAIR/Desktop/abcd/angular.min.js:52:329
    at q (file:///C:/Users/SARATH%20S%20NAIR/Desktop/abcd/angular.min.js:7:355)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't inject `$scope` like you are trying to do. This is not a service you can inject in directive. Correct code:

```
myApp.directive('removeMe', function () {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("click",function() {
                element.remove();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i have made an edit- added $rootScope as a dependency. Is that correct ?

Comment: This is the right answer, but the OP:s original code also had two more errors that are now in your answer too. Missing closing `)` from `element.bind` and using variable `element` when the parameter is named `elt`.

Comment: No, you can't inject scope into directive. The only scope object you can access is the one associated with a directive, and those is available in link (the first arg) and in directive controller as $scope service. You can' inject scope which is not assiated with element, and this happens when you create directive and try to inject scope like you are trying to do in you code.

Comment: @noppa Thank you for sharp eye!

Comment: @SarathSNair You **can** inject `$rootScope` the way you injected `$scope` originally. The main difference is that there will be only one instance of the `$rootScope` in the lifetime of the module. It is unclear though why you'd want to do that as you are not using `$rootScope` in the directive (nor should you).

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/21595931/2700949
It seemes you should use $rootScope and not $scope.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive("removeMe", function() {
      return {
            link:function(scope,element,attrs)
            {
                element.bind("click",function() {
                    element.remove();
                });
            }
      }
});
```

```html
<div class="showw" ng-app="myApp">
    <div id="hideDivOnClick" src="ddd.png" remove-me>Click me</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this sample. In my case it's worked.

**in HTML**

```
<button permission-code="'12012'" type="button">Email</button>
```

**in Script.js**

```
angular.module("myApp").directive("permissionCode", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            permissionCode: "="
        },
        controller: ["$scope", "$element", function ($scope, $element) {         

            if ($scope.permissionCode == '12012') {
                angular.element($element).remove();
            }

        }]
    };
});
```